# file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify): failed to open stream: in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation, recaptcha

It's working fine yesterday but today's it's not working and showing this error in my Laravel project.

Error: file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I'm using **"google/recaptcha": "~1.1"** for Google-captcha implementation.

My code for verifying Google Recaptcha

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $reCaptchha = new ReCaptcha(env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET'));
    $response = $reCaptchha->verify($value,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    return $response->isSuccess();
}
```

Please help me for remove this error.

Comment: Make sure your web host allows external HTTPS connections via `file_get_contents`

Comment: this error is for host, `Disk Usage` of your host is full